# how to order an arraylist asc with an especific class attribute?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with my class profile(Name and rated), I need to order asc this information in my Arraylist for the rated attribute.

for example:

- Name:john rated :50
- Name:Michel rated :30
- Name:Petter rated :55
- Name:Christian rated :78
- Name:Seba rated :60

I need this:

- Name:john Michel     :30
- Name:john rated      :50
- Name:Petter rated    :55
- Name:Seba rated      :60
- Name:Christian rated :78

Finally I want to get the best rated:

- Name:Christian rated :78

My class profile:

```
public class Profile {
    private String name;
    private int rated;

    public Profile(String name,int rated) {
        this.name=name;
        this.rated=rated;

        }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getrated(){
        return rated;

    }


}
```

I am trying with this, It doesn't work:

```
ArrayList<Profile> aLprofile=new ArrayList<Profile>();
    aLprofile.sort(aLprofile.get(0).getrated());
```

you have another way or any tip to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a comparator to the sort method. So use `Comparator.comparingInt` by providing the logic you want to compare your `Profile` instances with.

So in your case:

```
comparingInt(p1 -> p1.getRated());
```

that can be replaced with a method reference:

```
aLprofile.sort(comparingInt(Profile::getRated));
```

---

But if you want to only get the max, there's no need to sort, you can use `Collections.max`:

```
Profile p = Collections.max(aLprofile, comparingInt(Profile::getRated));
```

Comment: if I add attribute genre, how Can I get the max rated per Genre.

Comment: @Slinker You partition the input by genre and then for each one you find the max for each genre. Take a look at the Collectors class with the Stream API.

Answer (score 1):

Your class should implement the `Comparable` interface and then use `Collections.sort`.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Profile implements Comparable<Profile> {
    private String name;
    private int rated;

    public Profile(String name,int rated) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rated = rated;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getrated(){
        return rated;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Profile other) {
        return (getrated() - other.getrated());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Profile> aLprofile = new ArrayList<Profile>();

        aLprofile.add(new Profile("A", 10));
        aLprofile.add(new Profile("B", 8));
        aLprofile.add(new Profile("C", 12));
        aLprofile.add(new Profile("D", 14));
        aLprofile.add(new Profile("E", 6));

        Collections.sort(aLprofile);
        for(Profile p: aLprofile)
            System.out.println(p.getName());
    }
}
```